# Build Single Project in Xcode Workspace

Tags: ios, xcode

I have **XCode Workspace** in which i have **many Projects**. I don't want to **build entire workspace every time**. How can I **build a single Project** in Xcode Workspace?

In **Visual Studio** i can right click on project and select **project only->Build** but i didn't find any option in XCode..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a scheme for that. For reference: [XCode Scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH8-SW1)

I tried creating a workspace and added two projects in it. It appeared on the Menu (From which you select between device and simulators) for which project I want to fire build action.

Answer (score 5):

You probably should do it with schemes.
Open scheme and remove unwanted targets. From Build section. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: FWIW, in Xcode 10 at least, and maybe earlier, there were default schemes for each project in my workspace. I just had to select them and build.